# camera.setPreviewCallback rotate image

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I need to rotate the image 90 degrees in method camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback(){
Android save the image in landscape and i need it in portrait mode.
Is there any way to directly rotate the byte [] data ?

Comment: You can set the orientation. Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29

Comment: setDisplayOrientation only displays the camera in portrait mode, but the byte[] in  camera.setPreviewCallback is in landscape.
I need to rotate the image from byte[] data in camera.setPreviewCallback

Comment: @nahuelianni, you are overzealous this time. The question is quite legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO. There is no efficient way to rotate the preview buffers by 90°. You can setOrientation to have the preview displayed correctly; you can swap the YUV pixels in RenderScript or in C using JNI, but still, this will be a brute force rotation, and it will not be performed in-place.

If you do it for every frame callback, this may sum up to 30 frames per second, 1920x1080 pixels, almost 100MByte per second.

I strongly recommend to use the preview frames the way they arrive, landscape. If you need RGB pixels, you can convert YUV to RGB while applying rotation at almost no extra cost. If you need a downscaled image, you can resize and rotate at no extra cost.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rotate the byte data. You can simply set the rotation of the camera using the code below (assuming variable `camera` is your `Camera` instance:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setRotation(90);

camera.setParameters(params);
```

And you can set the preview rotation specifically by calling `camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);`

Here's a quick way of automatically checking the phone orientation and displaying the camera preview and saved image rotation accordingly:

```
int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

int degrees = 0;
switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
}

int result;
if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
    result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
} else {  // back-facing
    result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
}

params.setRotation(result);
camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

camera.setParameters(params);
```

Note that all of this is assuming you're still using the `Camera` class, which is deprecated for API 21+. However, the Camera2 api that replaced it is only available in 21+.